# Is there a plugin that makes Rhythmbox Smart Playlists more like iTunes?

Tags: rhythmbox, playlists

I'm in the process of moving completely to Linux and I noticed that Rhytmboxs Smart Playlist functionality is lacking one key feature (for me at least), that's the sub arguments, (I think that's what they're called)

In iTunes there are two levels to the Smart Playlists but in Rhythmbox there is just one. Is there a plugin that will allow me this extra functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what exactly is meant with sub arguments to smart playlists and iTunes-like levels but the smart playlists in Rhythmbox can quite nicely be adapted to personal needs.

On creating a new automatic playlist or when editing a playlist the following window will let us add several selection criteria like *"Time of Last Play"*, *"Rating"*, *"Artist"* to name only a view:

[image]

This criteria can be set to match **all** criteria or if ticked to match **any** of these criteria for inclusion in a playlist of unlimited or limited number of songs. In addition we are able to sort the playlist from various criteria.